# How do I prevent the video stream rotating in landscape - AVCaptureSession and OpenGL

Tags: ios, video, opengl-es

I have created an application that captures a live video stream, does some processing on the video stream using OpenGL ES, and displays it on a screen in a UIView

Essentially the data flow is:
     AVCaptureSession ->  AVCaptureDeviceInput -> AVCaptureVideoDataOutput -> gl buffers -> draws to a UIView

I am not using AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer for displaying the content.

When I display video using this system in portrait it works as expected, the video is in the same orientation as the display.

However, my app is intended to be used in landscape.   In my shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method in the superview I only allow UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft, and UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight.

My issue is that the video stream is rotated.   The phone is orientated to landscape, and the video stream is rotated by 90 degrees.  I would like the video stream to be in the same orientation.

I do not understand why the video stream is rotated, I guess it is trying to compensate for landscape mode, but I have not idea how to prevent this rotation.  Any ideas?

Thanks

Mike

---

Thanks for the response VinceBurn.

Ultimately I tried out the methods in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117756/rotate-some-uiviews-but-not-all)

And settled on the example code for willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if that would work, I'm just guessing something here.

If no simple solution comes, maybe try to apply a 90° rotation transform on your UIView layer.
(I don't like this idea, but could work)