# Manually override a single view's rotation animation?

Tags: objective-c, rotation, uikit, interface-builder

I have a view whose subviews adjust based on constraints (pre-iOS 6, no auto-layout). I rotate the device and the views animate into their new positions and dimensions as expected.

I add a new view to my XIB. This view will need to change position in a way that can't be described by constraints when the device rotates. Is it possible to allow the default rotation logic for all but the new view?

If not (and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117756/rotate-some-uiviews-but-not-all) suggests there is not) how should this case be handled?

I've tried adding my own animation simultaneously with rotation, but this is almost certainly wrong (the frame doesn't always end up in exactly the same place, presumably because the two animations are happening at once).

```
// Called on "viewWillAppear"
- (void)adjustLayout
{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation))
    {
        self.myView.frame = CGRectMake(150, 128, 181, 39);
    }
    else
    {
        self.myView.frame = CGRectMake(119, 148, 181, 39);
    }
}

// Called on willRotateToInterfaceOrientation
- (void)adjustLayoutToOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    // This is not really a good way to override the default animations, but it gets the job done.
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation))
        {
            NSLog(@"frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.myView.frame));
            self.myView.frame = CGRectMake(69, 201, 181, 39);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.myView.frame));
            self.myView.frame = CGRectMake(258, 94, 181, 39);
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to layout your custom view elements in the method:

`-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:`

All layout changes called during this block will be animated along with the standard rotation animations.

**Example:**

```
#import "OSViewController.h"

@implementation OSViewController

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation{
    return YES;
}

-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
    [self layout];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self update];
    [self layout];
}

-(void)update{

}

-(void)layout{

}

@end
```

Comment: Is your "layout" equivalent to my "adjustLayout"? Because if I call "adjustLayout" in didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:, my view ends up in the right place, but if I call it from willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:: it does not...

Comment: Yes, "layout" is equivalent to "adjustLayout", but the emphasis is that it is called in willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration: NOT willRotateToInterfaceOrientation ;)

Comment: Yup, that's what I meant in my comment. There is not a willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation without duration. Is this working for you? It's not working for me...

Comment: I updated the example to show the entire header which works correctly for me.  This is a base VC class I would extend and then override layout - it should accomplish your goal if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: I think I need to adjust my glasses (or at maybe buy some and then adjust them). Even after looking at it five time I somehow still was doing the code in willRotateToInterfaceOrientation. =) Bounty on its way in two hours or so (when I can award it). Thanks for your help.