# Finer grained UIView rotation in a UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, autorotate

I have a UIViewController that overlays controls on a view presenting what the camera sees. I have a couple of scenarios I would like to allow.

1. **For the iPad**, I want to keep the **controls on the right most edge** of the device, by your right thumb, no matter what the device's rotation. The **controls should rotate their content** so that their top is always upwards (away from the ground). I don't want the camera view to rotate at all, because that would just be silly – its position & size should stay the same and its contents shouldn't rotate either.
2. **For the iPhones**, I want to keep the **controls at the bottom of the device's screen**, by to the home button, wherever the home button actually is. The **controls should rotate their content** so that up is always pointing upwards. Again, I don't want the camera view's frame or content to take part in any view rotation animation at all.

I'm using auto-layout.

I'm wondering if there is any way to describe some or all of this in a storyboard. In particular, it'd be great to be able to describe that some view positions need to autorotate (ie, the controls, on iPad), but that other views don't (the camera view).

A [question from 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5117756/2547229) indicates this wasn't possible at the time, but perhaps things have moved on since then? If it's not directly supported, can you suggest an approach and are there some sensible places to be hooking in to autorotation to achieve this?

Comment: So, your parent view wants to be manual layout (so it doesn't rotate with the device), but its subviews (the controls) want to be autolayout?  Yeah, sounds difficult to coerce autolayout into doing that.  But, off the top of my head... I have a painting app where the canvas is stationary w.r.t. the device, but the controls always move to the bottom w.r.t. the orientation. I did that by counter-rotating the canvas away from the direction of rotation when the device orientation changes.  Maybe something along those lines...?

Comment: Hi @AnnaDickinson Ideally I want all the views to use auto-layout so I can have a single storyboard over different screen sizes / devices. Were you able to match your counterrotation animation to the auto-rotation animation so that the two canceled during the animation? That seems like it'd be useful to know!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this isn't quite a complete answer, but I tried a few things which look promising.

First, you can create a separate set of constraints for portrait vs. landscape using the size specifiers: landscape is w Regular, h Any; portrait is w Any, h Regular (I think -- double-check these) This is accessible via the pop-up control in the bottom-center of the storyboard view.  By installing different constraints for portrait and landscape, it should be possible to scale the width and height of your controls' container view so it appears to be in a constant position w.r.t. device orientation;  in other words, the container doesn't actually counter-rotate -- it scales so it effectively *looks* like it has counter-rotated.

I got this close to working.  It looks like it's doing the correct thing in the storyboard view, but when I actually run it, I get debug messages about conflicting constraints.  Not sure how to fix this, but maybe play with the constraint priorities?  That sometimes helps.

A second thing I (partially) tried was creating a custom container view class which counter-rotates itself to the correct position based on the device orientation (in the UIDevice class). You implement this by overriding layoutSubviews.  For each orientation, you define a transform which puts it in the correct position, and set the view's transform property.

Another possible solution is to override updateConstraints in your view controller and add/remove constraints to position/scale your container to the correct place for each orientation.

For all of these, the idea is that you "force" the container to be in the correct place, but leave the subviews (the actual controls) alone.  The controls should do the right thing if their constraints are independent of the specific orientation of the container view.

So, those are some ideas anyway... if they lead you to an actual solution, could you post it?  I anticipate having a need for this myself.

Comment: Hi Anna, thanks for giving this a shot! Sorry to take ages to reply. I did the boring option of just setting the transforms on some of my views to rotate them, but left the controller in portrait. In your suggestions you mention different constraints for landscape and portrait to provide the same size. This makes sense, but I don't see how it will actually prevent views in the controller (including the controllers content view) from rotating. They'll end with the same size, but they'll rotate to that end spot, no?